# arcgis server 10, vb.net, IMathOp problem

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, vb.net

i am using arcgis server 10 and visual studio with vb.net to build web mapping application. inside my code i have the following line:

```
Dim RasterCal As ESRI.ArcGIS.SpatialAnalyst.IMathOp = _
   New ESRI.ArcGIS.SpatialAnalyst.RasterMathOpsClass
```

or even if i do it this way

```
Dim RasterCal As ESRI.ArcGIS.SpatialAnalyst.IMathOp = _
   New ESRI.ArcGIS.SpatialAnalyst.RasterMapAlgebraOp
```

in both cases i get initialization error which says:

```
The runtime application type must be specified before license
 initialization.
```

plz can you tell me what is wrong with the above examples of lines? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create the objects on the ArcGIS Server SOC, so you most likely need to create ArcObjects via [IServerContext.CreateObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/003z/003z00000056000000.htm). See [Working with server contexts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_server_contexts/0001000001w1000000/) for more details.

If you really want to create ArcObjects on the application server or web server, you first need to bind to the desired runtime via [RuntimeManager.Bind](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Bind_Method/004600000024000000/). See the [Runtime Binding Requirement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002ns000000) section.

Since you are using Spatial Analyst specific classes, you will also need to checkout the Spatial Analyst extension license. More on this, along with an example, can be found [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000033w000000).

Comment: The following line worked for me...

    Dim pMathOp As IMathOp =   
       iServerContext.CreateObject("esriSpatialAnalyst.RasterMathOps")

thanks all!